# Concatenate Forename + Surname SelectCommand

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to concatenate a field of TeacherForename + TeacherSurname into my dropdownlist in order to make it clearer to the user on which Teacher they have selected.

However the TeacherForename + TeacherSurname will hold the value of TeacherID.

```
<div class="fields">
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="TeacherIdentification" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
            Width="150px">Teacher ID:</asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="TeacherForename"
            DataValueField="TeacherID" Height="29px" Width="155px" 
            CssClass="Dropdownlist">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT Class.TeacherID, Teacher.TeacherForename, Teacher.TeacherSurname FROM (Class INNER JOIN Teacher ON Class.TeacherID = Teacher.TeacherID)">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </p>
</div>
```

I have tried to do this myself but I can't get the select command right and it wont display in my drop down list, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="fields">
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="TeacherIdentification" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
            Width="150px">Teacher ID:</asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="TeacherForename"
            DataValueField="TeacherID" Height="29px" Width="155px" 
            CssClass="Dropdownlist">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT Class.TeacherID, (Teacher.TeacherForename + '' +     Teacher.TeacherSurname) as  TeacherFullName  FROM Class INNER JOIN Teacher ON Class.TeacherID = Teacher.TeacherID ">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would add an AS clause... SelectCommand="SELECT Class.TeacherID, (Teacher.TeacherForename + " " + Teacher.TeacherSurname) As TeacherFullName FROM (Class INNER JOIN Teacher ON Class.TeacherID = Teacher.TeacherID)" and in your Datasource change DataTextField="TeacherFullName"

Comment: Thank you! But apparently the server tag is not well formed and I can't see any errors...

Comment: Thanks for upadate, now i will be update and check it